# Symfony2 Doctrine Change Value on Entity Load

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a database structure which has a field `content`. In the database this is a `BLOB` (so a `string`). `content` contains a JSON-encoded string.

When I load this, I would like to load it in to a specific `Content` object (with a different `Content` subclass for each possible format of the JSON).

Are there any events or anything which I can hook up so I can catch the value right before the Entity is built (so I can have `setContent()` type-hint the `Content` class instead of having to be generic, which I'd have to do if the information is loaded in to the Entity before I intercept).

Any ideas?

---

A bit more details. Basically what I imagine is having some sort of Factory class which takes a JSON string and converts it to a proper object.

```
{
    body: "ABC",
    value: 5
}
```

Goes to an object of a class like this:

```
class MyContent extends Content
{
    protected $body;
    protected $value;
}
```

I can't use typical object mapping because it's a JSON string to an object.

---

Further clarification

Basically, I have an entity named `Box`. `Box` has a `content` value, which is supposed to be an instance of `Content`.

Under normal circumstances, if `Content` was a normal database Entity, I would just hook up a One-to-One relationship between `Box` and `Content`, which would load `Content` properly in to the `Box` without needing to do anything special.

However, in this case, `Content` can have many forms. To handle this, it is stored as a JSON object in a `BLOB` field in `Box`'s table. This means when Doctrine tries to load `Box`, it will try to load a string.

I could simply have `Box::setContent()` accept any parameter and deal with it accordingly based on if it is a string or `Content` object.

However, I'd like it so when it is used it is **always** a `Content` object, so I want type-hinting for the function (i.e., `Box::setContent(Content $content)`). The problem is this would prevent Doctrine from giving that field a string.

Which is why I want to intercept the value Doctrine has for `content` and replace it with a proper object before it loads it in to the entity `Box`.

I don't think any of the Doctrine events do exactly what I want, so it may not really be possible. =S

Comment: There's a [list of lifecycle events](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html?highlight=lifecycle#lifecycle-events) available in the docs. Not sure which one you might leverage for your case, might need a bit more info

Comment: What about loading the content object in the constructor of the entity class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately what I ended up doing was just creating different tables and Entities for each possible `Content` type and then using Doctrine's inheritence to let Doctrine handle them. Not idea (since there may be many, many types which means more tables and I can't just dynamically constructor new types), but it works well for now.

[Doctrine Inheritence](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/inheritance-mapping.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add code to the entities get method to do this. You can also check out the lifecycle call backs for doctrine: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/events.html#lifecycle-callbacks

Comment: I can't add it to the get method because then I can't use function type-hinting to only accept the proper object, because the data from the database is a string.

Comment: where are you trying to add the type-hinting?

Comment: To the `Box::setContent()` method. See my update to the question.

Comment: I still can't fully wrap my head around what you are doing. Would the `__toString()` method help?

Comment: Sorry, I missed this comment somehow. Basically, I need a sort of DataTransformer (http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html) for Doctrine Entities.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JMSSerializer to create entities from JSON - https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle.

And I can`t understand you question, but maybe you can use json_array type - http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#doctrine-mapping-types

You need to load data from DB and than create entities? Or load entities with some field that have nested entity deserialized from JSON?

Comment: I need to convert a string from the DB into an entity before it is assigned to it's associated entity.

Comment: You can hook in to entity manager lifecycle with http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#entity-listeners-class and use JMSSeriazer to deserialize content field and set it.

Comment: Which one though? The only one that seems relevant is postLoad, but that appears to be after it has already tried to create the entity. In my scenario (with a type-hinted field), that would throw an error.